# Broken urls in Jekyll in Docker

Tags: docker, url, jekyll

I have this problem I have Jekyll site that runs inside docker and the urls are broken because it use http://0.0.0.0:4000 as site url.

I'm using this to run docker:

```
docker run --rm -ti -v $(pwd):/tmp/www -p 8080:4000 jcubic.pl
```

and it execute:

```
CMD jekyll serve --host 0.0.0.0
```

I can access http://localhost:8080 but all urls are broken.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that in Jekyll if you use development mode it will replace the `{{ site.url }}` with current URL taken from host and port so it will be `http://0.0.0.0:4000`.

The solution found in this [issue on GitHub](https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/5743)

Use non-production enthronement, so your checks for production in code will not break (if you don't want to show something in development mode)

then add _config_dockerl.yml with:

```
url: ""
```

and run this:

```
# Dockerfile
CMD jekyll serve --host 0.0.0.0 --config _config.yml,_config_docker.yml

#bash
docker run --rm -ti -v $(pwd):/tmp/www -e "JEKYLL_ENV=docker" -p 8080:4000 image
```

That way `{{ site.url }}` will be empty string. It will only break in case where you need to pass real url with http (I had this with share buttons so I've enabled them only on production).